# why does selecting statements in sqlite not fetching any info when it exists

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to select from table using where condition and using parameters like follows:

```
cur.execute("SELECT GSTIN,\"Taxable Value\",CGST,SGST FROM books")
books = cur.fetchall()
for book in books:
    cur.execute('SELECT "GSTIN","Taxable Value", "CGST" ,"SGST" FROM twob WHERE GSTIN = ? AND "Taxable Value" = ? AND SGST = ? AND CGST = ?;',(book[0], book[1], book[3], book[2]))
    print(cur.fetchall())
    print(book[0], book[1], book[3], book[2])
```

Here books is extracted from another table and by using it i want to extract the same row where the following values are same still the `print(cur.fetchall())` is empty and i've checked it mannually using sqlite by entering book values manually using the exact statement, please guide me what am i doing wrong here.

the result is as follows:

```
[]
ABC 123 133424 23
[]
tushar 120 4353 424
[]
okay 240 1 45
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, There was a replacement in the excel file i was retrieving the data from between columns "SGST" and "CGST" thats why it was printing an empty list